# Scale svg background image discarding aspect ratio

Tags: css, svg

I have an svg image that I would like to scale, but when I scale it it keeps the aspect ratio so the bottom or top part of the image is cut off, is there something that I can do so it fills the page and doesn't keep it's aspect ratio?

This is what I am using:

```
body {
    background-image: url(/bg.svg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: top center;
}
```

I a not sure if this has an effect on anything, but I have this in the HTML as well

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: Check this article out...essential reading on svg scaling. http://sarasoueidan.com/blog/svg-coordinate-systems/

Comment: You could try making the url /bg.svg#svgView(preserveAspectRatio(none)) should work on Firefox, not sure about other UAs. Or just add preserveAspectRatio="none" to the bg.svg file's root svg element.